# XSL - need help combining two variables please

Tags: variables, xslt, concatenation

I need to combine two variables, one is a number like '11223344' and the other is two letters like 'AB'.

result I am expecting:  'AB11223344'

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/dataset">
        dataset>
            <xsl:variable name="modPatientID" select="attr[@tag='00100020']"/>
            <xsl:variable name="AccNum" select="attr[@tag='00080050']"/>
            <xsl:variable name="Prefix" select="AB"/>
            <!-- (0008,0050) Accession_Number -->
            <xsl:if test="string-length($modPatientID)=8">
                <xsl:if test="contains($AccNum,'_')">
                    <attr tag="00100020" vr="LO">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Prefix, $modPatientID)"/>
                    </attr>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </dataset>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This looks correct to me, but it does not seem to do what I'm expecting.  The output is only '11223344' and I'm looking for 'AB11223344'

does anyone have any ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select` attribute is an XPath expression, so

```
<xsl:variable name="Prefix" select="AB"/>
```

will set the variable `$Prefix` to a node set containing all the child elements named `AB` under the current context node.  If there are no such elements then the resulting set will be empty, which is why you're getting no prefix.

If you want the variable to contain the *string* `AB` then you need to quote it:

```
<xsl:variable name="Prefix" select="'AB'"/>
```

Here the `select` expression is a string literal rather than a location path.

Comment: Excellent!  that worked out great, I guess I was close, but clueless :)